# Xcode: NSCollectionViewItem does not have an outlet named imageView or textField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nscollectionviewitem

I would like to link an imageView and a textField in my xib grafical user interface to the belonging Outlets from the NSCollectionViewItem (which is an element from the application kit). But while linking the bindings following message pops up:

"Xcode cannont find a Key Value Coding compliant property named @property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7); in the class NSCollectionViewItem."

So, for me it is not possible to connect these objects. Therefore I don't get any Referencing Outlets for the Text Field or the Image View.

In an another xib the same bindings exist already. But they are marked with a white exclamation point and also show up a strange message: "NSCollectionViewItem does not have an outlet named imageView."

Does anyone knows how to solve the problem? Would be great.

Comment: Those outlets were added in 10.7. In the File Inspector for the NIB, what is the deployment target ("Build For") set to?

Comment: I am working with Xcode5 under OSX10.9, but I solved the problem by creating the bindings in the File Inspector with an older Xcode version. Now the bindings are working, but they also have the message: "NSCollectionViewItem does not have an outlet named imageView."

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and can confirm, regardless of the NIB's deployment target. It seems like an Xcode bug.

I created a custom subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` with no actual customizations. I set the class of the collection view item in the NIB to my custom subclass and the outlets were suddenly available. I then set the class back and they were still available. I connected one and built and got no warnings or errors.